# How to stop rendering component if some condition occurred in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, local-storage, jsx

I am building one Project (To-Do-App) with login functionality,
In this `Home` component I have to check if token is not set in the localStorage, then navigate to login component,

But after the navigate, `Home` component still renders and in this component I have an API call, so because of the token not found in localStorage, it throws an error "Unauthorized"

Home Component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import NotesContainer from "./NotesContainer";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";

function Home() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!localStorage.getItem("token")) {
            navigate("/login");

            // for toast
            toast.error("Please login", {
                position: "top-right",
                autoClose: 5000,
                hideProgressBar: false,
                closeOnClick: true,
                pauseOnHover: true,
                draggable: true,
                progress: undefined,
                theme: "dark",
            });
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <div className=" mt-4 px-2">
                <h1 className="text-4xl text-center font-semiboldbold underline underline-offset-2">
                    Your Notes
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div>
                <NotesContainer />
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

Inside `NotesContainer` Component I have API call.

NotesContainer:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import Note from "./Note";
import NoteModal from "./NoteModal";
import NoteContext from "../context/notes/NoteContext";

function NotesContainer() {
    const { notes, setAdding, setIsOpen, setCurrentNote, getNotes } =
        useContext(NoteContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        getNotes();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="px-3">
            <NoteModal />
            <div className="text-center mt-2 sm:text-end sm:mt-0npm st">
                <button
                    onClick={() => {
                        setCurrentNote({ title: "", description: "" });
                        setAdding(true);
                        setIsOpen(true);
                    }}
                    className="bg-slate-700 rounded-lg text-white text-md p-2 hover:scale-105"
                >
                    <span className="fas fa-plus "> </span>
                    &nbsp; Add New Note
                </button>
            </div>
            <div className="mt-3 flex justify-evenly flex-wrap gap-3">
                {notes.map((note) => (
                    <Note key={note._id} note={note} />
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default NotesContainer;
```

In current scenario, when I go to home component it will check for token, and if token is not set then it will navigate to `Login` component, but still home component is rendering and because of that my API call generate and throw an error.

[image]

So, I want that if token is not set in the localStorage then navigate to login before rendering the `Home` component so we can stop that API call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options available to you to avoid the `getNotes` call in the `NotesContainer` component. Here are a few suggestions.

1. Conditionally render the `NotesContainer` component only if there is a token value.

   ```
   import React, { useEffect } from "react";
   import NotesContainer from "./NotesContainer";
   import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
   import { toast } from "react-toastify";

   function Home() {
     const navigate = useNavigate();

     const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

     useEffect(() => {
       if (!token) {
         navigate("/login");

         // for toast
         toast.error("Please login", { .... });
       }
     }, [token]);

     return (
       <>
         <div className=" mt-4 px-2">
           <h1 className="text-4xl text-center font-semiboldbold underline underline-offset-2">
             Your Notes
           </h1>
         </div>
         <div>
           {token && <NotesContainer />}
         </div>
       </>
     );
   }

   export default Home;
   ```
2. Conditionally render the `Home` component's content or null if there is no token.

   ```
   import React, { useEffect } from "react";
   import NotesContainer from "./NotesContainer";
   import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
   import { toast } from "react-toastify";

   function Home() {
     const navigate = useNavigate();

     const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

     useEffect(() => {
       if (!token) {
         navigate("/login");

         // for toast
         toast.error("Please login", { .... });
       }
     }, [token]);

     if (!token) return null;

     return (
       <>
         <div className=" mt-4 px-2">
           <h1 className="text-4xl text-center font-semiboldbold underline underline-offset-2">
             Your Notes
           </h1>
         </div>
         <div>
           <NotesContainer />
         </div>
       </>
     );
   }

   export default Home;
   ```
3. Conditionally render the `Home` component's content or redirect if there is no token.

   ```
   import React, { useEffect } from "react";
   import NotesContainer from "./NotesContainer";
   import { useNavigate, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
   import { toast } from "react-toastify";

   function Home() {
     const navigate = useNavigate();

     const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

     useEffect(() => {
       if (!token) {
         // for toast
         toast.error("Please login", { .... });
       }
     }, [token]);

     if (!token) return <Navigate to="/login" replace />;

     return (
       <>
         <div className=" mt-4 px-2">
           <h1 className="text-4xl text-center font-semiboldbold underline underline-offset-2">
             Your Notes
           </h1>
         </div>
         <div>
           <NotesContainer />
         </div>
       </>
     );
   }

   export default Home;
   ```
4. Unconditionally render the `Home` component's content, including the `NotesContainer` component, and check for the token in `NotesContainer`.

   ```
   import React, { useEffect } from "react";
   import NotesContainer from "./NotesContainer";
   import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
   import { toast } from "react-toastify";

   function Home() {
     const navigate = useNavigate();

     const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

     useEffect(() => {
       if (!token) {
         navigate("/login");

         // for toast
         toast.error("Please login", { .... });
       }
     }, [token]);

     return (
       <>
         <div className=" mt-4 px-2">
           <h1 className="text-4xl text-center font-semiboldbold underline underline-offset-2">
             Your Notes
           </h1>
         </div>
         <div>
           <NotesContainer />
         </div>
       </>
     );
   }

   export default Home;
   ```

   ```
   function NotesContainer() {
     const {
       notes,
       setAdding,
       setIsOpen,
       setCurrentNote,
       getNotes
     } = useContext(NoteContext);

     useEffect(() => {
       const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

       if (token) {
         getNotes();
       }
     }, []);

     return (
       ....
     );
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than wait for your component to mount and run the effect hook (which is too late), use conditional rendering to render a [`<Navigate>`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/navigate) component.

This will avoid rendering your `<NotesContainer>` and thus any unauthenticated API calls.

```jsx
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

function Home() {
  // ...

  if (!localStorage.getItem("token")) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
  }

  return (
    <>
      { /* ... */ }
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it simple and easy:

```
Home Component:

 <>
      {!localStorage.getItem("token") 
       ?
       <>
            <Navigate to="/login"/>
       </> 
       : 
       <div className=" mt-4 px-2">
          <Home Component/>
       </div>
 </>
```

It will be better to use Context API to make a global auth state